# Can I get a ghost pregnant?

Tags: the-sims-3

Some of my Sims have recently been haunted by the recently deceased! My poor sim family never got around to conceiving a child before Mrs. Adrianna Morgan intercepted a meteor with her cranium. (Oops?)

So Charles Morgan, once-again bachelor and international super-spy, is kept awake at night by the tortured moanings of his late wife Adrianna. Since they were married in life, Charles has been rolling wants to see his dearly beloved. And then flirt with his dearly beloved. And then kiss his dearly departed. And, well, it goes on from there.

I know that male ghosts can impregnate female sims (though they don't show up in the family tree -- immaculate conception?), but is the reverse true? It's certainly not an option during Adrianna's midnight trysts.

I know Charles wants to get his ectoplasmic game on, but can he get viable heirs that way to boot? Or must he find a more corporeal "Ms. Right" to continue the family?

Comment: Yet another great Arquade title :D

Comment: I suppose I could just resurrect his wife. But where's the fun in that?

Comment: Now I see where they got the plot for the first season of American Horror Story.

Comment: I lol'd when I read this

Comment: I caouldent stop laughing when i read this - and Im on work now! +1 for the title!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can not impregnate a ghost while that ghost is tied but loosely to our world, but if she is brought partway back using [the science opportunity](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Oh_My_Ghost!), and made part of the active family, she can get pregnant and give birth as usual.

**Follow-up:**

Occult states in The Sims 3 are inherited, according to a fairly simple set of rules:

1. If both parents are normal sims, the offspring is a normal sim, irrespective of lineage in general.
2. If both parents are the same kind of occult, the offspring is the same type as their parents, and will inherit the occult details (such as wing shape, death type, etc.) from one parent or the other.
3. In all other cases, all occult-related inheritance comes from one parent *or* the other.

In all cases, only the parents are considered, and other genetics are blended as normal.

Unfortunately, ghosts don't work like other occults do; instead any child conceived by a ghost, or by a normal or occult sim in a ghostly state, will be a ghost, in addition to whatever occult states they might inherit.

Comment: Okay, follow up: Can the Ghost Mother give birth to a flesh & blood child, or only more ghosts?